# How to get current week number for that year from a date in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date, week-number

In MySQL,

```
SELECT WEEK('2019-01-07')
```

is showing week number 1.

But if I see, 2019 starts from Tuesday and current week for that date is week number 2.

How can I get the current week according to the year in this way?

Comment: See the manual under the relevant function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need [`WEEKOFYEAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear) function:

```
SELECT WEEKOFYEAR('2019-01-07'); # returns 2
```